Wordpress Woocommerce Custom Shop Site reverts to default Shop Site randomly
I have selected my own shop page under WooCommerce/Settings/Products/Shop-Site. This works for a while, but suddenly it shows the default WooCommerce page again.
Under the selection Shop-Site there is the following note: The base page can also be used in your product permalinks. Could it be related to that or what else could it be? Have I overlooked something?
